# Me gustaría saber si se puede pasar 2 arreglos A={1,2,3} y B={4,5,6,7,8,9} a otro arreglo = C {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Tags: c#, array

Tengo dos arreglos A y B, y quisiera pasar esos mismos datos a un arreglo C.
Este es mi codigo:

```
        //ARREGLO 'A'
        Console.Write("INGRESE LA LONGITUD DEL ARREGLO A: ");
        int contadorA = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] A = new double[contadorA];
        for (int i = 0; i < contadorA; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Posisión N.{0}: ", i+1);
            A[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //ARREGLO 'B'
        Console.Write("\nINGRESE LA LONGITUD DEL ARREGLO B: ");
        int contadorB = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] B = new double[contadorB];
        for (int i = 0; i < contadorB; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Posisión N.{0}: ", i + 1);
            B[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

No quiero sumarlos, quiero pasar los mismos datos al arreglo C

Comment: var C = A.Concat(B).ToArray(); Por cierto, no aconsejo utilizar int.Parse de esa forma, si el usuario escribe otra cosa que no sean números tu aplicación va a tronar.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, pero aún sigo aprendiendo por como vez es C# muy basico, como imprimo la variable C? porque al hacerlo así:             Console.WriteLine(C), me imprime en pantalla: System.Double[]

Comment: Además es solo para propositos escolares, el profesor no es tan estricto, aún. Pero claro que tomaré en consideración lo de los int.Parse para futuros codigos!

Comment: GRACIAS! Ya logré imprimirlo con un ciclo for!!

Comment: Es lo mejor, descubrir por uno mismo como se hace 

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de unir arrays

[Combine arrays](https://www.dotnetperls.com/combine-arrays)

usar el metodo de extension `Concat()` es una, pero tambien podrias usar el `AddRange()` de una lista

Para unir las listas y mostrar el resultado podrias usar

```
List<int> listTemp = new List<int>();
listTemp.AddRange(A);
listTemp.AddRange(B);

string listaString = string.Join(", ", listTemp.Select(x=> x.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(listaString);
```

como veras muy simple, solo necesitas convertir la lista numerica a string para poder unirla

[String.Join Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.5)